# Adding more number of parameters to sqlparameter class

Tags: c#, sql

I have to call a stored procedure but i am having more number of parameters is there any simple way to do this? or simply adding every parameter to sqlparameter class?? like below

```
 SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand("inserting", con);
 command.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
 command.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@Firstname", SqlDbType.NVarChar).Value = TextBox1.Text;
```

Answer (score 8):

Be aware that `Paramters.Add` has an [overload](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/wbys3e9s.aspx) that takes in a string and a DbType, so you don't have to call the Parameter constructor.  You could replace the line you are currently using to add a new parameter:

```
command.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@Firstname", SqlDbType.NVarChar)).Value = TextBox1.Text;
```

with the following shorter (but functionally equivalent) line:

```
command.Parameters.Add("@Firstname", SqlDbType.NVarChar).Value = TextBox1.Text;
```

**If you want to add more parameters**, you would simply add them to the [Parameters](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlcommand.parameters.aspx) property of your command, like so:

```
SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand("inserting", con);
command.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
command.Parameters.Add("@Firstname", SqlDbType.NVarChar).Value = TextBox1.Text;
command.Parameters.Add("@Lastname", SqlDbType.NVarChar).Value = TextBox2.Text;
```

Aside from that, have you tried using [Parameters.AddWithValue](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlparametercollection.addwithvalue.aspx)?  You can use this if the data type of your column maps to the type of your value in C#.  You can find a mapping of C# to SQL Server data typse [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms131092.aspx).

You would use it like so:

```
// Assume your sproc has a parameter named @Age that is a SqlInt32 type
int age = 5;
// Since age is a C# int (Int32), AddWithValue will automatically set
// the DbType of our new paramter to SqlInt32.
command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Age", 5);
```

If you need to specify the SqlDbType, AddWithValue returns the parameter you just added, so it's as simple as adding an extra statement to set the [DbType property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlparameter.dbtype.aspx) at the end, although at this point, you're better off just using the original .Add function and setting the value.

```
command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Firstname", TextBox1.Text).DbType = SqlDbType.NVarChar;
```

Comment: The `.AddWithValue()` is a bit dangerous - since you're not specifying the datatype of the parameter, ADO.NET must guess from your value what you want. It's doing a good job at guessing - but it's still just guessing, and sometimes this guess can be horribly off. So I would always recommend to specify the `SqlDbType` for your `SqlParameter` and thus not use `.AddWithValue()` ....

Comment: I wouldn't say that figuring out which DbType is used by AddWithValue is just guesswork, but it's definitely not the right tool for every situation.  I added a link to the MSDN article that shows C# to SQL data type mappings and added information about the overload of .Add that will allow the user to not have to call the parameter constructor themselves.

Answer (score 5):

Use Array of type SqlParameter and insert that into SqlCommand

```
SqlCommand Comm = new SqlCommand("Command text", new SqlConnection("Connection String");
SqlParameter[] param = {new SqlParameter("@Name","Value"), 
                        new SqlParameter("@Name","Value"),
                        ........
                        };
Comm.Parameters.AddRange(param);
```

Comment: what is value here??you mean textbox value?

Comment: yup. The values to be inserted in the Db like Name, City, Age etc

Comment: i know this is old but is more advantageous writing your sqlparameters in array form like you wrote, or just writing  them in sequence such as:
        cmd.Parameters.Add(New SqlParameter("@name", name))
        cmd.Parameters.Add(New SqlParameter("@startdate", startdate))
        cmd.Parameters.Add(New SqlParameter("@enddate", enddate))

Answer (score 1):

Just call the `command.Parameters.Add` method multiple times:

```
 SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand("inserting", con);
 command.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;

 command.Parameters.Add("@Firstname", SqlDbType.NVarChar, 100).Value = TextBox1.Text;
 command.Parameters.Add("@Lastname", SqlDbType.NVarChar, 100).Value = TextBox2.Text;
 command.Parameters.Add("@City", SqlDbType.NVarChar, 100).Value = TextBox3.Text;
 command.Parameters.Add("@ID", SqlDbType.Int).Value = Convert.ToInt32(TextBox4.Text);
 ....... and so on .....
```

Comment: ya i am doing like this only but i am asking about is there any simple way to do this or this is the only way?? as i am having more number of parameters to pass.....

Answer (score 1):

You may use like it

```
return new SqlParameter[]
            {
                new SqlParameter("@Firstname", SqlDbType.VarChar)
                {
                    Value = Firstname.Text
                },
                new SqlParameter("@Lastname", SqlDbType.VarChar)
                {
                    Value = Lastname.Text
                },
            };
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use [dapper-dot-net](http://code.google.com/p/dapper-dot-net/)

sample code:

```
var dog = connection.Query<Dog>("select Age = @Age, Id = @Id", new { Age = (int?)null, Id = guid });
```

Insert example:

```
connection.Execute(@"insert MyTable(colA, colB) values (@a, @b)",
    new[] { new { a=1, b=1 }, new { a=2, b=2 }, new { a=3, b=3 } }
  ).IsEqualTo(3); // 3 rows inserted: "1,1", "2,2" and "3,3"
```

Answer (score 0):

The `command.Parameters.Add` is deprecated. Rather use `command.Parameters.AddWithValue` .
For this, you would call it many times for each parameter.

Answer (score 0):

```
  // Mention size of the nvarchar column   , here i give 500 , you can use its length for @Firstname as you mention in database according to your database 

   SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand("inserting", con);
 command.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
 command.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@Firstname", SqlDbType.NVarChar,500).Value = TextBox1.Text;
```